# Redirect 301 a single URL using htaccess or routes.php

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect, routes, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect /es/services to /es/servicios but I'm unable to do it, I've tried on .htaccess with

> Redirect 301 /es/services mydomain.net/es/servicios

But nothing happens, also wanna say only on /es language so how can I do it?? I'm using laravel 5.5

Thanks!

Comment: Look that https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#redirect-routes

Comment: 5.5, sorry, look here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#redirect-routes

Route::redirect('/here', '/there', 301);